# Regular expression to validate mathematical formula in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression pattern to validate simple mathematical equations.  The equation must begin with a positive or negative number (integer or decimal, any size, which can possibly have a leading decimal, e.g., .08).  Then any number of the following (step 2): +, -, *, or /, then another positive or negative number (integer or decimal, any size, which can have a leading decimal).  Step 2 can be repeated 1 to unlimited times.  Parentheses are not allowed.  It's only numbers (including decimal numbers, positive or negative) and operators (+-*/).

For example, these are valid equations:

-1+.1+100+111111

2-2

-100.01/200*-3+4000000.8688--.742

These are not valid equations:

1+

88..88+77..77

I've gone through numerous iterations, and here's where I'm at:

@"^([-]??((\d){0,}(.\d{0,})?)){1}([-+/*]{1}[-]??((\d){0,}(.\d{0,})?)){1,}$"

That matches this: -22.22*-22.22/-.22 (GOOD)
But it also matches this: -22.22* (BAD)

I think my issue has something to do with greedy or lazy syntax.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible. You will need a proper parser. Have a look at ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm ) or ( https://github.com/i-e-b/DBSS/blob/master/DBSS/Calculations/Calculator.cs )

Comment: This was marked as duplicate, but the other question includes parentheses and functions average and sum.  What I'm asking is simpler than that.  It's numbers (positive or negative, integer or decimal numbers) with operators in between.

Comment: So it's a "number", followed by one-or-more "single operator plus number"? With the tricky part that a `-` can be both an operator and a part of a negative number

Comment: By the way, you don't need to specify `{1}`, as that is default

Comment: I've posted several _`Regular expression to validate mathematical formula`_ accepted answers on SO since 2015. Why isn't this a _Duplicate_ of one of my post's ?

Comment: Reclaiming the punitive loss penalty for you +1, from that same guy.

Comment: with `var numre = @"-?(\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)";`, this: `var re = new Regex(@$"^({numre})([-+/*]({numre}))+$");` will give the correct answer for all your testcases

Comment: For a complete regex `^(?:[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))(?:[-+/*][+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))+$` https://regex101.com/r/ZvQRkW/1 Doesn't include exponents or whitespace, nor duplicate signs/operations of the plus/minus variety that resolve to a single sign. There is no such thing as a minus operation. There is only addition, multiplication or division of negative or positive numbers.